# What is the meaning of T D P S S S C I when I get output of usb-devices on terminal?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I want to get USB bus port details (which have USB serial ID number, USB type, USB name, port type, port name, and many other data points) in Ubuntu.

I typed `usb-devices` where I got a certain no of rows starting with T, D, P, S, etc.
[image]

Someone help me in identifying these terminologies.

Answer (score 2):

According to source code: https://github.com/gregkh/usbutils/blob/master/usb-devices

- T: Transport
- D: Device class
- P: Product vendor id
- S: String
- C: Configuration
- E: Endpoint
- I: Interface

Comment: I got the terminologies. Thanks